# Javascript click element by X Y not working

Tags: javascript, click, simulate

Hey guys I am working on a script to help me out on soundcloud. On soundcloud, each track has a waveform that you can click on to skip to certain parts of the track. I want to simulate a mouse click on the waveform of a song but I need some help.

I need to be able to click at varying parts of the waveform, not simply on the element's position.

I wrote the following code to find the coordinates of the waveform (just execute it in address bar while on any track):

```
(function(){ alert(document.getElementsByClassName('g-box-full sceneLayer')[0].getBoundingClientRect().top); })();
```

For me the coordinates are 678, 296.

If I wanted to, for example, click a few seconds into the track I though I would be able to do:

```
(function(){ document.elementFromPoint(750, 310).click(); })();
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. Nothing happens. I want to be able to execute the javascript from the address bar via `javascript: <code here>`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sadly, I don't think you can. I've tried thoroughly simulating a click (just calling the `click` method on the element isn't sufficient) with the right X and Y values, etc., and it doesn't do what a real click does. They're probably checking the `isTrusted` flag to ignore simulated clicks.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot! You're probably right about the isTrusted flag